# ubuntu & haskell : problem with haskell-vim-now

Tags: linux

I just installed haskell-vim-now from this site ( [here](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now) ) but when I launch vim and I enter text, such as an hello world haskell example, no code colors are displayed, nor completion : I wonder if something has really been installed (althought the haskell-vim-now seems to have been installed without errors)

Maybe I forgot something, but I can't see what.

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try [the troubleshooting on its wiki](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now/wiki/Installation-Troubleshooting) or [the issue tracker](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now/issues)?

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled syntax highlighting and filetype plugins/indentation in your vimrc?

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: Hello,  I installed emacs and it seems to work fine. Thanks anyway

Comment: @lolveley I fail to see how that's a solution to getting Vim to work with haskell-vim-now.